# Cauchy sequence in operator theory.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Let $X\ne \{0\}$ a Banach space, $\rho(T)$ is the resolvent of an operator $T$.

**Proposition.**  Let $T\colon D(T)\to X$ a linear closed operator. We have that $$\lambda\in \rho(T)\iff(T-\lambda I)\quad\text{is bijective}$$

**Proof.** The implication $(\Leftarrow)$ is clear.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Since $(T-\lambda I)$ is continuous, exists $K\ge 0$ such that $\lVert(T-\lambda I)^{-1} \rVert\le K\lVert x\rVert$ for each $x=(T-\lambda I)y\in \text{Ran}(T-\lambda I).$

Then for all $y\in D(T)$, since $(T-\lambda I)y=x\in \text{Ran}(T-\lambda I), $ we have $$\lVert y\rVert=\lVert (T-\lambda I)^{-1}[(T-\lambda I)y]\rVert\le K\lVert (T-\lambda I)y\rVert\tag 1.$$

Since $\overline{\text{Ran}(T-\lambda I)}=X$, if $x\in X$, exists a sequence $\{y_n\}\subseteq D(T)$ such that $(T-\lambda I)y_n\to x.$

**Question.**$\{y_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

**My answer.** We use the $(1)$ and the fact that the sequence $\{(T-\lambda I)y_n\}$ is a Caichy sequence, since it is convergent.

It's correct?

Comment: Be careful, you obviously echanged the direction of the two implication arrows you used

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.